# Send push message triggered from Firestore if stock price is above/below some point

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I've started a new iOS project recently and for the first time I'm using Google Firebase, in specific the Firestore database.

My app allows you to keep track of specific stock values. Now it should be able to send a push message to all subscribed users if the stock value falls or rises above a specific value.

My data within Firestore is structured this way:

```
rates
 - stock#1
      - name, price, lastUpdated ...
```

So my idea was to add an firebase cloud function that listens to an update on "stock#12" and send the push notifications to everyone subscribed.

Thats where I'm stuck now. Sounds easy, but I'm not sure about a few things:

- How should I handle subscription to a specific stock price? In specific, how to handle the firestore structure for this, are there any best practices?
- The next step would be, how to send the push notifications? Is this possible with cloud functions in this case?

Comment: Yes, You can achieve this using cloud functions. From iOS app, the user has to subscribe for the stock whose notification, he wants to receive notification. You can subscribe user using the code without any user interaction.

Comment: To send a push notification, write a cloud function, which invokes whenever any change in stock value. Within function, you need to check, whether you need to send notification or not based on you specific value.

Comment: Does this example in documentation describe your exact usecase: [Notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens)?